# R runif and rnorm producing same random numbers with vector operation

Tags: r, random

I am trying to generate random data with R's `runif` and `rnorm` functions, where these functions are supposed to add some "noise" to the generated data. However, they are producing the same random number when I apply them as part of a vector addition operation.

Below is an example where `x` is an independent variable. I would to generate `y` and `z`, which are dependent output variables with a little "noise" added to them by the random number generators. The noise is supposed to change randomly with every new value of `x`.

```
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- x + runif(1)
z <- x + rnorm(1,mean=2, sd=0.5)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
df
#     x         y        z
# 1   1  1.364842  3.10679
# 2   2  2.364842  4.10679
# 3   3  3.364842  5.10679
# 4   4  4.364842  6.10679
# 5   5  5.364842  7.10679
# 6   6  6.364842  8.10679
# 7   7  7.364842  9.10679
# 8   8  8.364842 10.10679
# 9   9  9.364842 11.10679
# 10 10 10.364842 12.10679
```

As seen above, each random number generator is creating identical values. Why is this happening? **How can I fix the problem so that they generate different random numbers every time they are added to the `x` variable in the vector addition operation?**

Here is proof that the two functions are working correctly. I did not set any seed value.

```
runif(1)
# [1] 0.05202364
runif(1)
# [1] 0.02315487
rnorm(1,mean=2, sd=0.5)
# [1] 1.714753
rnorm(1,mean=2, sd=0.5)
# [1] 1.369988
```

Comment: When you do `runif(1)`, what is the `1` for? (Look at `?runif` if you need to...)

Comment: @Gregor: I was expecting that `runif(1)` would produce 1 different random variable for every value of `x`, just as typing `runif(1)` would produce 1 different random for every time I type it into the R interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- x + runif(10)
```

`runif(1)` indeed produces just one value which is added to a vector.

so you could do it like this as well with the same result:

```
x_runif <- runif(1) # create one random value
y <- x + x_runif
```

Comment: I see. You have to create a separate vector of random numbers first, and then add it to the data vector. That doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: Not intuitive perhaps for someone who is expecting the runif code to be implicitly called for every new row. Such might be expected by someone used to the macro languages SAS or SPSS. R is different. We have objects and recycling rather than "sets" and row-wise calculations in data steps.